# Treeview - Treenode - VB.Net - Not Displaying Nodes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, treeview

I'm trying to add nodes from a dataTable into a treeview. My problem isn't the adding of the nodes however, it is displaying them.  My loop goes through and adds every node.  I have a text box that displays the total nodes correctly.  However the treeview displays nothing.  Am I missing some display property?

Thank you for your help!

```
    oldComments.DataBind()
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim TreeView1 As TreeView = New TreeView
    ' TreeView1.FindNode("My Node").ChildNodes().Add(New TreeNode("Test This"))
    For Each row As DataRow In dsData.Rows
        Dim node As TreeNode = New TreeNode(row("UpdateTimeStamp").ToString)

        Dim node2 As TreeNode = New TreeNode((count.ToString + " - Count"), "test")
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node2)
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node)
        TreeView1.Nodes(0).ChildNodes().Add(node)
    Next
    TreeView1.ExpandAll()
    status.Text = TreeView1.Nodes.Count
```

Then the ASP:

```
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="My Node" Value="My Node"></asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
```

I have added one node to see where it was displaying / try to use the find control to add a new child node and that didn't work.  Suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the same node twice. Once to the treeview nodes and once to the child nodes of another node. You do not need to assign a node to the treeview itself if you are adding a child to some node. Change the code to

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node2)
node2.ChildNodes().Add(node)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are adding all of your nodes to the wrong `TreeView`.

You have already declared the `TreeView` in your markup as "TreeView1".  So this line:

```
Dim TreeView1 As TreeView = New TreeView
```

should be removed, and the rest of the code should still work just fine.

This assumes your `TreeView` is directly on the Page at the "top level" and not in some kind of container (like an `UpdatePanel`).  If *that's* the case, you would need to first use `FindControl` to get the `TreeView`.

So, rather than removing the line above, you would replace it with something like this:

```
Dim TreeView1 As TreeView = someContainer.FindControl("TreeView1")
```

<sub>Also, that code probably needs to be running in the `Page_Load` section of your code behind (if it is not already).  but I don't really think that's the problem.</sub>

Comment: Good catch.  However once I changed it to the treeview on the page, it still didn't display .

Comment: @Greg Have you tried the code in the other answer?  That is an additional problem here: When you do `TreeView1.Nodes(0).ChildNodes().Add(node)`, it's essentially removing the node that you added before and making it a child of node2.  That could be causing some confusion.

Comment: Yeah, my code started working...  I have no idea why.  I came back from lunch and accidentally went into this part of the site and the tree view displayed.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Greg Don't you love it when that happens =P  Well, good luck to you and I'm glad I could help.